# Excel VBA to create every possible combination (without repetition)

Tags: vba, excel

i need help with the following excel and what looks like a VBA problem.

The idea here is to generate all the possible combination (without repetition) in each grouping.

INPUT

```
COLUMN A | COLUMN B

A | 1

X | 1

D | 1

C | 2

E | 2
```

OUTPUT

```
COLUMN A | COLUMN B

A | X

A | D

X | D

X | A

D | A

D | X

C | E

E | C
```

What I managed to do.... how do i let it run only if the data is in the same group.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim CountComb As Long, lastrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    CountComb = 0: lastrow = 1

    For i = 1 To 10: For j = 1 To 10

        Range("G" & lastrow).Value = Range("A" & i).Value & "/" & _
                                     Range("B" & j).Value

        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        CountComb = CountComb + 1
    Next: Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I fail to see where the problem is... just need to set up a few variables, don't you?

Comment: I tried to use formula in Excel to get it done, but it seems an impossible task without VBA. And I do not know how to start with VBA.

Comment: @user1839229 you know, I am somewhat a bit sorry, your question/questions got closed, because I think, that you do have a good question here, just asked it in a very unlucky way. You should edit your initial question, trash this one and try to get the original reopend, now that you're showing some effort to solve this on your own.

Comment: Voting to reopen - there is no point closing this as a duplicate of his original question when the original has also been closed - he'll never get an answer.

Comment: what is the purpose of the numbers in column B, they can be ignored?

Comment: @PhilipABarnes no they can't be ignored. The comments of the original post had the answer: these numbers represent groups - so AXD is a group and CE is a group. That is why there are no combinations of C or E with A,X or D in his example.

Comment: done and edited my post below.

Answer (score 1):

see below. **Note you need to add the reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime in Tools >> References**. Change the Range("A1:A5") to either a dynamic named range or static range and the routine will handle the rest for you. It displays the results starting in G1 but you can also change this / make dynamic as an offset from the data range. Up to you.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Dim Data As Dictionary

Sub GetCombinations()

    Dim dataObj As Variant
    Dim returnData As Variant
    Set Data = New Dictionary
    Dim i As Double

    dataObj = Range("A1:B5").Value2

    ' Group Data
    For i = 1 To UBound(dataObj) Step 1

        If (Data.Exists(dataObj(i, 2))) Then
            Data(dataObj(i, 2)) = Data(dataObj(i, 2)) & "|" & dataObj(i, 1)
        Else
            Data.Add dataObj(i, 2), dataObj(i, 1)
        End If

    Next i

    ' Extract combinations from groups
    returnData = CalculateCombinations().Keys()

    Range("G1").Resize(UBound(returnData) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(returnData)

End Sub

Private Function CalculateCombinations() As Dictionary

    Dim i As Double, j As Double
    Dim datum As Variant, pieceInner As Variant, pieceOuter As Variant
    Dim Combo As New Dictionary
    Dim splitData() As String

    For Each datum In Data.Items

        splitData = Split(datum, "|")
        For Each pieceOuter In splitData
            For Each pieceInner In splitData

                If (pieceOuter <> pieceInner) Then

                    If (Not Combo.Exists(pieceOuter & "|" & pieceInner)) Then
                        Combo.Add pieceOuter & "|" & pieceInner, vbNullString
                    End If

                End If

            Next pieceInner
        Next pieceOuter

    Next datum

    Set CalculateCombinations = Combo

End Function
```

Comment: not sure why SO is removing the whitespace to make it hard to read!